# Product of 2 numbers exclusively in Kivy language (.kv file) - why the order is important?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to multiply 2 numbers, performing it exclusively in the .kv file.

So I created this minimalistic `main.py` file:

```
from kivy.app import App


class Test(App):
    pass

Test().run()
```

and this minimalistic `test.kv` file:

1. My 1<sup>st</sup> approach:

   ```
   BoxLayout:
       TextInput:
           id: num_1
           text: "8"
       TextInput:
           id: num_2
           text: "4"
       Label:
           text: f"Product: {int(num_1.text) * int(num_2.text)}"
   ```

   After launching the application, I obtained the error

   > ```
   >  >>    9:        text: f"Procuct: {int(num_1.text) * int(num_2.text)}"
   >  ...
   >  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
   > ```

2. My 2<sup>nd</sup> approach – I changed only *the order* of widgets, putting the Label before TextInputs:

   ```
   BoxLayout:
       Label:
           text: f"Procuct: {int(num_1.text) * int(num_2.text)}"
       TextInput:
           id: num_1
           text: "8"
       TextInput:
           id: num_2
           text: "4"
   ```

   and I obtained the expected result

   [image]

   (which correctly reflects changes in TextInputs).

**So the question is: Why my first approach didn't work?**

---

*Note:*

I'm not interested in a better solution or some workaround, I want only understand, why my first `test.kv` file don't work.

---

**EDIT:**

If in my 1<sup>st</sup>, not working approach, I change the text of Label to `num_1.text + num_2.text` (concatenation of strings), it works!

Comment: Are you sure your question shows the actual .kv files you're using

Comment: @DarkKnight - yes, I am (copy/paste).

Comment: If that's the case can you explain why the label text begins with "Procuct" but the value displayed is "Product"?

Comment: @DarkKnight, you caught me! ;-) When I saw the output of my app, I noticed this typo, so I corrected it in my code and put the corrected image of output into my question, but I forgot to correct it in my copy/pasted code, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the order that `kivy.builder` does things. It creates widgets from top to bottom in your `kv` file, but it assigns attributes of those widgets in the reverse order (I have no idea why). Here is a slight modification of your code that shows the order of things:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    MyTextInput:
        id: num_1
        text: "8"
    MyTextInput:
        id: num_2
        text: "4"
    MyLabel:
        text: "Product: " + str(int(num_1.text) * int(num_2.text)) if num_1.text != '' and num_2.text != '' else 'unknown'
'''

class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyTextInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print('Called TextInput init, text =', self.text)

    def on_text(self, instance, new_text):
        print('on_text:')
        print('\ttext set to', new_text)

class MyLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print('Called Label init, text = ', self.text)

    def on_text(self, instance, new_text):
        print('on_text:')
        print('\ttext set to', new_text)


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

Test().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems that it explains that behavior, **but**... If in my 1st approach I change the text of Label to `num_1.text + num_2.text` (concatenation of strings), *it works*! How to explain it?

Comment: Your answer really helps me, now I understand, where the problem is. I don't want “steal” your answer and create my own one, so here is an idea how to fix it. — Your hypothesis about the reverse order is likely not correct. The matter lies in default values: — In my first, not working example, Kivy sees an expression in the Label's text property, so it substitutes the default values for (so far not processed) TextInputs text properties (empty strings). But my expression requires converting them to integers, which fails. If my expression only concatenates strings, this issue doesn't arise.

Comment: It is partially dependent on the order. When the attributes defined in a `kv` file depend on `Properties` of other objects, bindings are created to those `Properties`. If the `Label` is first in the `kv`, it gets its attributes set last, so the `TextInput` already have their `text` `Properties` set. If the `Label` is last in the `kv`, it gets the default `Properties` of the `TextInput` objects. So, a general fix is to use a conditional in the `kv`, like this: `text: "Product: " + str(int(num_1.text) * int(num_2.text)) if num_1.text != '' and num_2.text != '' else 'unknown'`.

Comment: If you run my code with the above change, you will see the `Label` text gets set to `unknown`, before it gets set to `32`.